# How to captrue real-time network traffic in RPL using contiki?

Tags: iot, contiki, icmpv6, rpl, 6lowpan

I'm working on intrusion detection in the Internet of Things based RPL.
I need a 6LoWPAN network dataset to evaluate IDS.
How to capture live (Real-Time) network packets and traffic analysis in a Cooja simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Please, explain more:
Cooja will simulate such a network, you can visually see the topology, arrange nodes, etc., plus, you can capture the packets through Cooja in multiple ways: You can just copy from the Cooja output screen, or save to a file and further analyze. Is that your goal?
Look at this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.future.2021.07.013.

Comment: Thank you,John.Usually I use cooja->tools->radio messages to generate pacp.file.Then use wireshark to open it.It's discontinuous.I want to collect traffic and save it right away.Is there any good way?

Comment: Yes, you can enable the serial ports of the sink and any nodes you want, and dumb the output in real-time there. Then you can connect directly to the serial ports (pty, pseudo-terminal) and do whatever you want with the traffic. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks very much!Any node can be link with serial port?I will have a try.

Comment: Yes, all nodes can be directly accessed via serial port. You just have to open each node's serial port (right click-> menu-serial) and open one or more pseudo terminals. I believe you will find it easily (I don't have contiki handy right now, but if you want more, let me know)

Comment: Hey,John.Do you know sensniff and how to deploy it in network?

Comment: No, sorry, never used it.